# Ionic 5: Runtime Error: undefined is not an obejct

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework

Im using ionic 5.x on my macOS

I'm simply trying to pop data from an array but get a runtime error :
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.mapsPlaceholder.pop')

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, latLng, tileLayer, Layer, marker, icon, Util } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {

  map: Map;
  // Before map is being initialized.
  mapsPlaceholder: any[] = [];

  //...

  setMarker(x, y, iconImage, popupText){

    //...

    marker([x, y], {icon:mapIcon})
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup(popupText,{autoPanPadding:[150,75],closeButton:false,autoClose:false,closeOnEscapeKey:false})
      .on('mousedown', function () {
        this.map=this.mapsPlaceholder.pop();
        console.log("mousedown! ");
      })
      .on('mouseup',function (){
        console.log("mouseup! ");
      })
      ;
  }

}
```

Comment: do you fill the `mapsPlaceholder` array?

Comment: Yeah, earlier in the code I have a ```this.mapsPlaceholder.push(map)``` 
The weird thing is it doesn't indicate an empty array it just says my array is undefined when I ```console.log(this.mapsPlaceholder)``` just before the pop()

Comment: could you copy/paste the error?

Comment: ```ERROR
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.mapsPlaceholder.pop')
(anonymous function) — tab2.page.ts:59
fire — leaflet-src.js:593
_fireDOMEvent — leaflet-src.js:4452
_handleDOMEvent — leaflet-src.js:4409
onInvokeTask — core.js:34182
runTask — zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask — zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask — zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback — zone-evergreen.js:1640```

Here it is

Comment: try change the callback to an arrow function, like: `function() => {`

Comment: And where are you pushing value?